# MATLAB: Calling a superclass' method from parfor

Tags: matlab, inheritance

Let us get directly to the code. There are two classes. The superclass is

```
classdef Parent
  methods
    function this = Parent()
    end

    function say(this, message)
      fprintf('%s\n', message);
    end
  end
end
```

The child class is

```
classdef Child < Parent
  methods
    function this = Child()
      this = this@Parent();
    end

    function say(this, message)
      for i = 1
        % This one works...
        say@Parent(this, message);
      end

      parfor i = 1
        % ... but this one does not.
        say@Parent(this, message);
      end
    end
  end
end
```

The question is: How to make the *second* loop work without introducing any additional methods? As for now, it raises an error saying "A base class method can only be called explicitly from a subclass method of the same name." Thank you.

Regards,
Ivan

Answer (score 1):

I think you may need to explicitly cast `this` to `Parent` before calling the `parfor` loop, and then call the `Parent` method `say` explicitly:

```
this2 = Parent(this);
parfor i = 1:1
  say(this2, message);
end
```

In order to do that, you need to modify the constructor of `Parent` to accept an input argument:

```
function this = Parent(varargin)
    if nargin == 1
        this = Parent();
    end
end
```

If `Parent` and `Child` had properties, as your real classes probably do, you would include some code following the `if` statement that would assign the `Child`s properties to the newly constructed `Parent` object.